# No internet connection on windows start, but i have a connection to the local network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Everytime i start windows i have a working connection to the router and the local network with no warning sign on my wireless network icon. To be able to connect to the internet i have to disable and re-enable my wireless network card in the control panel. Anyone knows why this is happening? Or does anyone know how i could automate this disable/re-enable the network card process with batch every startup?

Im using:

Window 7 64-bit
ZyXEL Dual-Band Wireless AC600 USB Adapter
Eset Smart Security 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with this simple script

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface name="Hetyer 5Ghz" admin=disabled
netsh interface set interface name="Hetyer 5Ghz" admin=enabled
```